# showing popup form every hour after login in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

In my application i want a div popup after user login and that popup will shown every hour on time of login. div popup will shown with form of one textbox and submit and if the user do not submit any data before second div popup shown that form should be submited automaticaly with empty data and data should be stored into the data base. now the issue is how to show div popup every hour if i use inverval in javascript its only client side and on refresh the value of interval will be changed so javascript will not used.second option is to use session but when user clear histry it will loss the data .i m confused how to do this think .how i can show popup every hour after the login entry. popup showing will be continued every hour untill user do not logged out.Is it possible ?

Comment: On login you can store timestamp in a cookie and then on each page load you can check if the timestamp is older then an hour then show popup and update cookie to new timestamp

Comment: ya but when the user need to clear a cookie it will loss the time na.

Comment: You can also use browser `sessionStorage` instead of cookie. `sessionStorage` is supported by most modern browsers including IE8.

Comment: yes but if you are using login based on cookies than he will be logged out as well

Comment: ok login time is set in cookie whenever user logedin its right and  in another variable i store time+1 hour ok.but now when to check that condition that login time and login+1hour is match or not.  ex  : login_time=10.30 and showing popup time 11.30 but when to check that time is 11.30 or not

Comment: I got another idea, why dont you set cookie for 1 hour expiry, no need for setting timestamp as cookie value, and on each page load you check if cookie does not exists than show popup and create cookie, this will automatically serve your purpose with out need of any comparison

Answer (score 0):

maybe try using a session variable that will reset after a set amount.

```
<?php
session_start();
$inactive = 3600;
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
if (isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
    $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
    if ($sessionTTL > $inactive) {
        // reset the timer (*not tested)
         $_SESSION["timeout"] = time() -3600;
        // add popup code
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks but the condition is like .login time=10.30 timer strat from 10.30 too .and user will clear the session data when timer is on half an hour from the login time (approx 11am ) data will loss.and when user loged in next time at 11am  the timer will start from 11am  to 12am and popup will shown on 12am its 1and half hour. but i want hourly timer only